# Implicit conversion from type to interface in C# -- Basic example works, but actual implementation has a compile-time error

Tags: c#, interface, implementation

Take the following simple example:

```
interface IVehicle {
}

class Car : IVehicle {
}
```

Now I should be able to do the following:

```
IVehicle vehicle = new Car();
```

And indeed if I create these base classes as above, I receive no compilation errors (and the code runs.)

But in my project wherever I'm doing something essentially like that (as far as I can see) I get the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Namespace.Path.Car' to 'IVehicle'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Sometimes (as in different code locations, not different compiles) the explicit cast works and sometimes it compiles but creates a runtime exception (invalid cast). Why does the basic example work without issue, and a more detailed class (but still a single class that directly implements the interface) has all these issues?

In some situations, it'll actually come up with this compile-time error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Namespace.Path.IVehicle' to 'IVehicle'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I think I'm missing some important condition that is required for this implicit cast to work, but I have not found what difference causes the simple example to work and the more detailed class to fail so strangely. The only thing I've seen of note is that the compile time error only includes the namespace on the first type (as shown in the above two errors), but I can't remember if that is normal or not.

To remove any environmental causes, I created a test case with just the following code:

```
ISimpleInterface simple = new SimpleImplementation();
IComplexInterface complex = new ComplexImplementation();
```

The above causes a compile time error on the second line (indicating it cannot do the implicit conversion).

Comment: Based on the error message I would guess the most likely problem is htat you have 2 `IVehicle` types in the compilation.  The code you write should work in all cases except that one

Comment: Post the class and interface definitions for your failing case (`IComplexInterface` / `ComplexImplementation`)

Comment: Can we see the declarations of your class and corresponding interface? I would also like to see the line of code where this implicit case is being attempted and failing. Please include the `using` statements of each file, you might be accidentally pulling in classes froma  different namespace than you expect. E.g. Is there two IVehicle interfaces and you are accidentally using the wrong one?

Comment: You've left out the details that would allow one to answer the question. If you can supply an example of code that will cause these errors, we can address them specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what's causing it. This interface is being used as the WCF service contract. Svcutil is apparently creating a duplicate of the interface in the global namespace. Since they were in different namespaces, there was no compilation error. The part about the error indicating two different names (one with the namespace, one without) was an indicator that this was causing it.

Comment: well... pretty much what I said in my answer, but oh well.

Comment: Correct, but I wanted it to be clear that the problem was being caused by WCF. I understand I didn't mention this in my question, but if someone else runs into the same problem I want them to be able to find it. If you have a better suggestion as to how to mark this resolved (while retaining the WCF part), I'll change it.

Comment: no, thats ok. The most important thing is that it will help others that might google this up.

Answer (score 8):

You have either two types named `IComplexInterface` *or* two types named `ComplexImplementation` in different namespaces.

Remove [using statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and use full qualifiers for the types and see if it resolves the problem. Navigate to the implementing class double check so that it implements the same interface as you are assigning to. Pay careful attention to to what *namespace* the the interface and class lies in.

Answer (score 2):

Indirect interface instantiation is normal. As defined for brevity in your question, the example will compile and run.

```
public interface ICar{}
public class Viper : ICar{}

ICar fun = new Viper();
```

Pretty basic stuff, although usually this will be wrapped in some sort of Factory pattern. Either way, the process is common and therefore the problem must lie in your implementation.